# What is the best way to organize project files in Heroku with Clojure?

Tags: heroku, clojure

[I am working on the Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-clojure#local-workstation-setup) to get started with Clojure but I am having difficulty with the names and locations of my files.

I put the source file `world.clj` in src: `src/hello/world.clj` as instructed. This is my directory now

> C:\Users\a\CLOJURE\P2\helloworld\src\hello\world.clj

This is my `project.clj`

```
(defproject helloworld "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "helloworld project to test heroku and clojure"
  :url "http://helloworld.herokuapp.com"
  :license {:name "license1"
            :url "http://example.com/FIXME"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [compojure "1.1.1"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.0"]
                 [ring/ring-devel "1.1.0"]
                 [ring-basic-authentication "1.0.1"]
                 [environ "0.2.1"]
                 [com.cemerick/drawbridge "0.0.6"]]
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :plugins [[environ/environ.lein "0.2.1"]]
  :hooks [environ.leiningen.hooks]
  :profiles {:production {:env {:production true}}})
```

When I try to run this locally with `lein run -m hello.world 5000`

I get the following error

```
  C:\Users\a\CLOJURE\P2>lein run -m hello.world 5000

  java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate hello/world__init.class or 
  hello/world.clj on classpath:
  ....
```

Can you explain what is the best way to organize my files and naming conventions?

---

**EDIT**

I created a `CLASSPATH` as Environment Variable and added `C:\Users\a\CLOJURE\P2\helloworld\src\hello` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/Funfun/hello_heroku/tree/master/clojure

Comment: I have my files set up exactly the same way but I still get the same error.

Comment: i'v got all running nicely. http://pastie.org/8379858 Windows OS as you can see. Change your project.clj as an example.

Comment: Great, thanks! I was not running it from my project directory, now it works: `C:\Users\a\CLOJURE\P2\helloworld>lein run -m hello.world 5000` Do you want to create an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I also found out that CLASSPATH is also required.

Comment: ok, i added an answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38678/discussion-between-codegroover-and-zeynel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is:

```
$ cd clojure_project
$ lein run -m hello.world 5000
```

http://pastie.org/8379858